# The request won't go through api path

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making a post request with jquery to '/get_access_token' url. but it is not going through. In postman the request is stuck in 'Sending'. Below I'm adding the code.

app.js

```
const myRouter = require('./src/routes/myRouter ');
app.use('/get_access_token', myRouter );
```

myRouter,js

```
 //this is inside myRouter
    const express = require('express');

    const myRouter= express.Router();
    const myController = require('../controllers/myController');


    function router() {
      debug('inside router');
      const { getAccessToken } = myController();
      debug(getAccessToken);
//from here it is not going down
      myRouter.route('/get_access_token').post((request) => {
         debug('inside api call');
         const result = getAccessToken(request);
      });
    }

module.exports = router;
```

myController.js

```
  const client = require('path to client');
  function myController() {
  function getAccessToken(request) {
    debug('inside getAccessToken');
    const PUBLIC_TOKEN = request.body.public_token;
    Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.exchangePublicToken(PUBLIC_TOKEN, (error, tokenResponse) => {
        if (error != null) {
          reject(new Error('Could not get access token'));
        }
        const ACCESS_TOKEN = tokenResponse.access_token;
        const  ITEM_ID = tokenResponse.item_id;
        debug(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        debug(ITEM_ID);
        resolve('Access Token was acquired succesfully');
      });
    });
  }
  return {
    getAccessToken
  };
}

module.exports = myController;
```

jquery request, only the portion when there is a public token

```
onSuccess: function(public_token) {
    debugger;
    $.post('/get_access_token', {
      public_token: public_token
    }, function() {
      $('#container').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#intro').hide();
        $('#app, #steps').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue

`module.exports = router;`

Router is the function, not the router actually, it cannot work.

It can theoretically work if you exports the `myRouter`, but you have to define it properly.

I suggest to find some "express boilerplate" on internet, make it work and then just update that code to your needs

Comment: ah, I forgot to return the router at the end of the function. (I just started with node)